# How to use a variable produced in a method in other methods?

Tags: java

Basically, i need to use the value of `spaces` from this method `spacesCount` in another method, or in the main void run. But it won't let me use outside?

Thanks for your help, sorry new programmer here.

```
public static int spacesCount(String str){
    int spaces = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
       if(str.charAt(i) == ' '){
         spaces++;       
       }
    }
    return spaces;
}
```

Comment: The OP says s/he is a new programmer and is sorry, we may give him/her a break by not downvoting. Anyway, welcome to Stackoverflow @user3023003!

Answer (score 5):

You are providing the value of `spaces` as the return value from the method.  So you need to store the result in a variable and use it in your other method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String myString = "this is a test";

    int spaces = spacesCount(myString);
    // use spaces to do something
}
```